# Different user in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, admin

I am new in asp.net mvc 4. Could you tell me how to do that when I put `username==admin && password==password123!` it open the Admin page. Where to put the code because I don't know?
I want also that another user that isn't Admin can't see the other user data.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some additional information?  Do you already have a sign in page?  It looks like you're using forms authentication, but do you have any of it working, some or all?  Let us know how far along your sign-in process is and any decision you've made (like using a custom membership provider).  Thanks

Comment: I have used the standard log in. I have used this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: But here everyone that register and log in can see, edit and delete the other user's data... So I want that a user can see or modified his own data and admin all users data.. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a large subject and there are a number of ways to handle authentication and authorization in MVC 4.

This [tutorial covers using Microsoft's default authentication and authorization providers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) with a local SQL database to store the credentials.

Your first tutorial created the UI to get sign-in information, but doesn't check it against a back-end source like a SQL database or active directory or anything else (xml, other DB types, web service, openAuth providers, etc).  This second tutorial will show one way of wiring up the data, but you will need to decide whether that's how you want to store credentials.

Specifically on your question of allowing admin's only to see a user maintenance page you can do this using [Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).  In the tutorial i linked to you'll see a code sample where the "AdministratorSecrets" action had an attribute above it that looks like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public ActionResult AdministratorSecrets()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will prevent anyone but an administrator from seeing the view that AdministratorSecrets returns.  You can use this to have an admin maintenance page that only admins can see.

You may want to have full control over the sign in process and over managing user's roles (so you can accept a hardcoded admin password and return the admin role for that user).  If the tutorial doesn't give you enough control, then you can finely tune your solution by writing a CustomMembershipProvider (to handle the sign-ins) and a CustomRoleProvider (to handle figuring out what roles each user has).

Check out this tutorial if you want to go the custom route: http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx

Comment: I have this problem in my code:private int getIdByUser(string p)
{
  using (var DbContext = new SurveyContext())
    {
        List<SurveyContext> surveys = (from s in DbContext.Surveys
                                           where s.userName = userName
                                           select s.id).ToList();
        if(surveys.Count() > 0)
                    {
                       int id = 0;
                       int.TryParse(Surveys.First(), id);
                       return id;
                     }
                     return 0;
     }
}

Comment: Hey @radiolaDollani, please post it as a separate question and include the error message and what line it occurs on.

Comment: List<SurveyContext> surveys = (from s in DbContext.Surveys
                                       where s.userName == s.userName 
                                       select s.ID).ToList();

Comment: problem is at "ToList"...   Error1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System

Comment: The second error: Error 2 The name 'Surveys' does not exist in the current context in the "Surveys" code below:
if(surveys.Count() > 0)
                    {
                       int id = 0;
                       int.TryParse(Surveys.First(), id);
                       return id;
                     }
                     return 0;

Comment: Hey @radiolaDollani Please post these problems in a new question

Comment: I post in a new question.. :)